# Computing the sum of values after a give algorithm

Tags: php, math, sum

I have to implement an algorithm in PHP and I got stuck.

I have the following table: http://cl.ly/image/1Z0K1g0z2c3y

For each iteration, the (S) value is computed as such:

S1 = V1 - P1

S2 = (V1 - P1) + (V2 - P2)

S3 = (V1 - P1) + (V2 - P2) + (V3 - P3)

and so forth.

My array of values looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (            
            [v] => 131.44            
            [p] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [v] => 155.00
            [p] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [v] => 168.64
            [p] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [v] => 131.44
            [p] => 131.44
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [v] => 280.00
            [p] => 280.00
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [v] => 117.80
            [p] => 117.80
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [v] => 70.68
            [p] => 70.68
        )

    [7] => Array
        (            
            [v] => 58.90
            [p] => 58.90        
)
```

Is it possible to compute this sum for each iteration using a for() loop?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? It looks like you could just put the values from the table into a multidimensional array and iterate over it with `for` (or `foreach`).

Comment: I have updated the post with the array example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Assuming the array you've updated to is called $table:

```
// $S is array for S where sums are stored
$S = array();
$S[0] = $table[0][v] - $table[0][p]; // Perform the first row
for ($i=1; $i< count($table); $i++) { // Start at 2nd and continue on
  $S[$i] = $S[($i-1)] + ($table[$i][v] - $table[$i][p]);
}
```

Now all the $S values are populated as such. If you want to add to the table:

```
$table[0][s] = $table[0][v] - $table[0][p]; // Perform the first row
for ($i=1; $i< count($table); $i++) { // Start at 2nd and continue on
  $table[$i][s] = $table[$i-1][s] + ($table[$i][v] - $table[$i][p]);
}
```

---

Yes you can, considering you want the S values of 1, 2, 3 ... then yes. I assume V is an array and P is an array so you'll have to change accordingly, since each S can be based off the previous, I keep a running_sum value so that we don't have to iterate over previous values of V and P, we just use the last value of S:

```
// $V is array for V and $P is array for P and 
// $S is array for S where sums are stored
if (count($V) == count($P)) { // Check both V and P are same length
  $running_sum = 0;
  for ($i=0; $i< count($V); $i++) {
    $running_sum += ($V[$i] - $P[$i]);
    $S[$i] = $running_sum;
  }
}
```

We really don't need the running sum variable though but I used it to make the logic clear, here it is without it:

```
// $V is array for V and $P is array for P and 
// $S is array for S where sums are stored
if (count($V) == count($P)) { // Check both V and P are same length
  $S[0] = $V[0] - $P[0]; // Perform the first row
  for ($i=1; $i< count($V); $i++) { // Start at 2nd and continue on
    $S[$i] = $S[($i-1)] + ($V[$i] - $P[$i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: In the first code block, in the for loop, doesn't it have to be ($table[$i][v] - $table[$i][p]) instead of ($table[0][v] - $table[0][p]) ?